# Add borders to current and adjacent cell in a given range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of data which has a combination of merged/unmerged, empty/non empty cells. I currently have the code which skips the empty cells in a given range and adds border to non-empty cells. Here is the code which I wrote.

```
Set iRange = ea.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(EAlastrow, EAlastcol))
   For Each iCells In iRange
       If iCells.MergeCells Then
          If Not IsEmpty(iCells) Then
             Dim iCellRange As String
             iCellRange = iCells.MergeArea.Address
             Range(iCellRange).BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin
          End If
      Else
         If Not IsEmpty(iCells) Then
            iCells.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin
         End If
      End If
Next iCells
```

Is it possible to set the range in a way that it includes below empty cells too and add a border to it?

This is how the table is structured:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [Range.Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) could help you?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey: I tried using Range.Offset. However, I am not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SubFormat()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngHeader As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DblLastRow As Double
    Dim DblMaxLastRow As Double
    
    'Setting RngHeader as the first line of the data i want to be formatted.
    Set RngHeader = Range("A2:AB2")
    
    'Checking which is the highest value of non empty row for each column of RngHeader.
    For Each RngTarget In RngHeader
        DblLastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, RngTarget.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        DblMaxLastRow = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DblMaxLastRow, DblLastRow)
    Next
    
    'If no data has been found, the macro is terminated.
    If DblMaxLastRow < RngHeader.Row Or _
       (DblMaxLastRow = RngHeader.Row And Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngHeader) = RngHeader.Cells.Count) _
    Then
        MsgBox "No data found", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No data found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Targeting the data.
    With Range(RngHeader.Cells(1, 1), Cells(DblMaxLastRow, RngHeader.Cells(1, RngHeader.Columns.Count).Column))
        
        'Setting the borders' format.
        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin, xlColorIndexAutomatic
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to twig the code a bit to meet my requirements but this was really helpful. Thanks @EvilBlueMonkey for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it works fine for me:

```
Sub ALLBorders()
   With Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
       .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin, xlColorIndexAutomatic
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Here is the second requirement solution.**

```
Sub BorderMultiRange()
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A28:A29,C5:E9,G11:J14")
.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Borders.Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to include the empty cells (A28-29, C5-E9, G11-J14,etc.) in the range too?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last cell with data for each column and then set border for each cell in that column till the last cell with data. In below code 3 indicates column C

```
lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C1:C" + CStr(lastRow)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Comment: This might work. But then I'll have to do this for each columns separately? The data I have has columns till 'AB'. Will it be possible to loop through every column and pull the last row of it and add a border? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can define the range A1:AB1 and loop through its cells for example. You can also use a double type variable to register the highest value of last row for each column and with that define the exact size of the range you want to edit and then apply the wanted format.